# opt in for window.resizeTo?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, window-resize

I'm building an in-browser application for my company's internal use. It would be helpful if my users could quickly switch between 6 different browser dimensions. I've tried using window.resizeTo, but it seems most modern browsers are disabling any sort of coded resizing.  Safari seems to be my only exception for Mac users, but I'm concerned that they too will follow suit with Chrome and FF.

Is anybody aware of any work-arounds or user opt-ins?  I've found a Chrome extension that can get the job done, but ideally there wouldn't have to be any sort of configuration or 3rd party extensions as some of my users have very strict permissions on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. Otherwise all kind of ads would ask the user to allow them to resize themselves in the hope some people allow it (and thus most likely allow it for the whole adserver used by tons of websites).

Comment: Yah that's what I figured.  I guess I was just secretly hoping that there was a setting like "Allow javascript to do horribly annoying things to my browser".  Oh well, designers on Macs are my target audience and Safari still allows this.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your application's content in a `<div>` with `overflow: scroll`, and resize that actual `div`. If your application's styles do not allow that, you can wrap it in an `<iframe>` with the viewport size you want to enforce.

Comment: That's a clever idea. I like the iframe, but I believe it will break a requirement of this application.  Since it is being used by designers to get layout approval, this application will need to mimic the style and functionality of our production site almost exactly.